# Force iPad to download a CSV file

Tags: php, ios, ipad, mime-types, content-type

I have a web app in which some data is being exported and imported through CSV files. The users don't really have any meaning from opening them directly, so I'm forcing the browser to download the file, so they can save or forward the data to someone else.

I am using the following headers (in PHP):

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"name.csv\"");
```

This seems to work on PC's and phones (Android and Windows phone), but it doesn't work on iPads. iPad always shows the contents, and then doesn't offer any forward or share options (except opening or sharing the link to the page, which wouldn't work because you'd have to be logged in).

Can I force iPad to download it, or at least offer the option to attach the CSV file in a new email?

Comment: iOS devices can't download content from web, it will show content if readable.